# Simultaneous diophantine approximation

Tags: diophantine-approximation, nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $r(x)$ be the function $x$ mod $1$, i.e. $x$ minus its floor.

Now let $m$ be a given positive integer, and $c$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ whose components are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, where (without loss of generality) the first component is $c_1=1$. Is the set of points $(r(c_2n),\ldots,r(c_mn))$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, dense in the $(m-1)$-dimensional unit cube? (It is known that the origin is a limit point, under weaker assumptions.)

If not, is anything known about vectors $c$ for which this is the case?

Answer (score 11):

This is true, and known as the [Kronecker Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem) on diophantine approximation.

Comment: Thanks for this - but your link doesn't work. Sources I have looked at suggest that Kronecker did just the case $m=2$. Do you have a reference for the general case?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the link.

Comment: And according to Springer encyclopedia, he proved an even more general result in 1884, see http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=k/k055910

Answer (score 7):

Let me share a simple proof I found during a childbirth class 8 years ago:

Let $x_1,\dots,x_d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $1,x_1,...,x_d$
are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $a_1,\dots,a_d\in\mathbb{R}$ be
arbitrary. We want to show that there are $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y_1,\dots,y_d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$|nx_i-y_i-a_i|<\epsilon,\qquad 1\leq i\leq d.$$
We proceed by induction on $d$, the case of $d=0$ being trivial. So let us assume that $d\geq 1$ and the statement holds for $d-1$ in place of $d$. The initial hypothesis is invariant under replacing $x_i$ by $nx_i-y_i$ for any
nonzero $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and any $y_1,\dots,y_d\in\mathbb{Z}$, while the conclusion only becomes stronger. Hence by Dirichlet's theorem on simultaneous diophantine approximation we can  assume from the beginning that
$$|x_i|<\epsilon,\qquad 1\leq i\leq d.$$
By the induction hypothesis applied to the $d-1$ numbers $x_1/x_d,\dots,x_{d-1}/x_d\in\mathbb{R}$,
there are $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y_1,\dots,y_{d-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
such that $r:=(m+a_d)/x_d$ satisfies
$$|rx_i-y_i-a_i|<\epsilon/2,\qquad 1\leq i\leq d-1.$$
Moreover, this inequality also holds for $i=d$ if we set $y_d:=m$. Now let $n$ be the closest integer to $r$. Then
$$|nx_i-y_i-a_i|\leq |rx_i-y_i-a_i|+|(n-r)x_i|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon,\qquad 1\leq i\leq d.$$
The proof is complete.

**Added on 24 November 2023.** In fact the proof above is essentially the same as the one in Estermann: A proof of Kronecker's theorem by induction, J. London Math. Soc. 8 (1933), 18-20. It also appears in Section 23.8 of Hardy-Wright: An introduction to the theory of numbers.

Comment: "found during a childbirth class" that would be a good addition to an article of Günter Ziegler on where maths can be done :-)  http://www.gegenworte.org/heft-16/ziegler16.html (text in German)

Comment: @quid: That's a great link, thank you!

Comment: There is a flaw in the last line : ║(n-r)x║ is not lower than ║x║/2 because ║ ║, which means "distance to ℤ^d", is not positively homogeneous. Anyway, this proof cannot hold because it does not use the (necessary) hypothesis of linear independence but only that the x_i's are nonzero.

Comment: I think my proof is ok. I really meant that $\| \|$ is the norm in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and from the very beginning we can assume that $\|x\|<\epsilon$ because we can replace $x$ with $mx+y$ for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}^d$. The independence hypothesis is used at two places: first we use that replacing $x$ with $mx+y$ as above leaves the hypothesis invariant, second we use it in the induction hypothesis in the form that $x_i/x_d$ for $i=1,\dots,d-1$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I clarified my proof above, please check.

Comment: Thank you very much, and shame on me !!! I put your proof on http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Théorème_de_Kronecker_(approximation_diophantienne)

Comment: Thanks for checking my proof carefully and putting it on Wikipedia. Please mention "GH from MO" and provide a link to this page.

Comment: Nice proof - much simpler than anything I've seen before. As a point of
perfectionism: you may wish to remove extra "such that" and restate the
sentence starting with "The statement does not change..." (the statement
*does* change, what you really mean is that replacing the $x_i$ with
$nx_i-y_i$ with a suitably chosen $n$ and $y_i$, one can assume without
loss of generality that $|x_i|<\epsilon$).


Comment: @Seva: Thank you. I agree with your comment. I updated the text, please check.

Comment: Nice argument, thanks for sharing! I have one suggestion: in the induction step explicitly state that you choose $a_i - \frac{x_i}{x_d} a_d$, for $i=1,\ldots,d-1$.
I also have one correction: since you induction argument uses $d-1 \geq 1$, it supposes that $d \geq 2$. Thus, you must start the induction proving $d=1$, the one-dimensional Kronecker Theorem, which you must assume since your induction argument does not prove it.

Comment: @LucasSeco I don't use $d\geq 2$ in the induction step. If $d=1$, then I use the induction hypothesis for $d-1=0$ in place of $d$, which is the trivial base case ($d=0$). In particular, if you spell out the induction step for $d=1$, you get a proof of the one-dimensional Kronecker Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do see that $d=1$ is the statement of one-dimensional Kronecker Theorem, but I do not understand what is the statement of the induction step for $d=0$: could you please clarify?

Comment: There is no induction step for $d=0$. The induction step is meant for $d\geq 1$: we reduce the statement to the case of $d-1$ in place of $d$. As written in the proof. Please follow the proof line-by-line, and tell me which step is unclear.

Comment: The proof of the induction step is pristine clear, but the proof of the $d=1$ step is not clear, unless you are assuming the one-dimensional Kronecker Theorem in which case there is nothing to be proved.

Comment: @LucasSeco There is some basic misunderstanding here. Let $P(d)$ denote the statement we want to prove: for any $x_1,\dots,x_d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that etc. (see lines 2 to 4 of my post). So we want to prove $P(d)$ for every integer $d\geq 0$. For this it suffices to prove $P(0)$ and the implication $P(d-1)\Rightarrow P(d)$ for every integer $d\geq 1$. Now $P(0)$ is trivial, while the implication $P(d-1)\Rightarrow P(d)$ is established in lines 5 to 17 of my post. I edited my post slightly for clarity. In particular, $P(1)$ is true as it follows from the trivial statement $P(0)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146365/discussion-between-lucas-seco-and-gh-from-mo).

Comment: @LucasSeco I don't want to discuss this further. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is answered (positively) in the first two chapters of W. Schmidt, "Diophantine approximation." Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 785. 1980.

Very well written and not too long. The case of m=2 is treated separately, as it is especially elegant. More - in the case of m=2 - it is estimated how well you can approximate various numbers with growing n.