# Number theory question 

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Given $a$ and $b$ irrational numbers with $a/b$ also irrational, how do you prove that
$( \{ na\} , \{ nb \})$ is dense in $[0,1] * [0,1]$ , where $n$ ranges over the integers?

$\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ .

I'm also curious about the general case, with $n$ irrational numbers , linearly independent over $Q$ , resulting in density over $[0,1]^n$ .

Comment: You don't. Take $a=\sqrt 2$ and $b=1+\sqrt 2$. The correct condition is that $1,a,b$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Weil's criterion does the trick in no time giving even the equidistribution property.

Comment: @fedja, you meant Weyl's...

Comment: Right! $\\ \ \ $

Comment: For the general (and correct) statement you can find a quick proof here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106819/simultaneous-diophantine-approximation

Answer (score 5):

Just google Kronecker's approximation theorem.